# Python & MySQL - non GCC module?

Tags: python, mysql, database

Are there any MySQL modules that are written purely in Python and don't require GCC to be compiled? MySQLdb is great but it just requires too much for what I'm working with right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick. All python, no gcc.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python